# Dropdown list in HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, dropdown, html-select

I need to take UniversityID from the University selection to list institutes in this university for Institute Selection. I read it is easy with AJAX but I couldn't solve it. For now Institute selection show all the institutes.

*Institute_1* and *Institute_2* in **University_1** 
*Institute_3* in **University_2**

I want to show *Institute_1* and *Institute_2* in Institute selection if user chose **University_1** 
 or 
 *Institute_3* if user chose **University_2**

How I can write AJAX part or is there any better way?

```
<label>University</label>
    <select name="University" id="University">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM University";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['UniversityID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['University_NAME']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <br>

    

    <label>Institute</label>
    <select name="Institute" id="Institute">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Institute ";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['InstituteID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Institute_NAME']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <br>
```

Comment: You should trigger a ajax when there is a change in your selection of the university (say calling a PHP file) , which return the query result to the part on the institute select box . (do you want some sample codes or would you like to try it yourself ?)

Comment: what you want to show `Institute` in select option on the  change of `university` in select option??

Comment: please show us your database table structure also, there is `university id`  present in `institute table`.

Comment: @KUMAR yes in the institute table there is also university id.

Comment: @KUMAR i want to show Institute Names at the university I selected above

Comment: @KenLee some samples can be good, thanks

Comment: Please see my answer for the sample codes

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now.

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice day (and let's look forward to a better 2021).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following sample codes to achieve what you want (Ajax call) :

**HTML (place this file in a web server to run please)**

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<label>University</label>
<br>
    <select name="University" id="University" onchange="javascript:trigger1();">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="UID01">MIT</option>
    <option value="UID02">Harvest University</option>
    <option value="UID03">Stanford University</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    

<label>Institute</label>
<div id=result>
<select name=Institute id=Institute>
<option value="">Please select University First
</select>
</div>


<script>
function trigger1()
{
var1=document.getElementById("University").value;
//alert(var1);



$.ajax({
 method: 'POST',
url: 'http://www.createchhk.com/getfaculty.php?uid='+var1,
    success: function(response){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=response;
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log("There was an error: ", request.responseText);
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

**PHP (getfaculty.php)**

```
<?php if ($_REQUEST["uid"]=="UID01") { ?>
<select name="Institute" id="Institute">
<option value="Arts">Arts
<option value="Science">Science
<option value="Medicine">Medicine
<option value="Engineering">Engineering
</select>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($_REQUEST["uid"]=="UID02") { ?>
<select name="Institute" id="Institute">
<option value="BBA">BBA
<option value="Arts">Arts
<option value="Science">Science
<option value="Medicine">Medicine
<option value="Engineering">Engineering
</select>
<?php } ?>


<?php if ($_REQUEST["uid"]=="UID03") { ?>
<select name="Institute" id="Institute">
<option value="Music">Music
<option value="Science">Science
<option value="Medicine">Medicine
<option value="Engineering">Engineering
</select>
<?php } ?>
```